# half Skyrmion vs Meron

Tags: quantum-field-theory, superconductivity, skyrmion

Is there a difference between a half skyrmion and a meron? I'm asking this in regard to half skyrmion theories of High Tc Superconductors. It would be interresting to know if the proposed half skyrmions which emerge in the disturbed antiferromagnetic spin structure are actually merons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meron) are in general another name for half-[instantons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton), while half-[Skyrmions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyrmion) are merons (and anti-merons) in the special case of [nonlinear sigma models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_sigma_models) that support Skyrmions.

Comment: @P3trus is asking about magnetic spin configurations. While these can be mapped to the NLSM language, the field theory Wikipedia articles are probably not terribly helpful. In their context, there is no such distinction.